# How to specify enclosed by in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I am writing a pig script i have data which is space separated and in some of the columns there are  spaces in between but it is enclosed by double quotes(") below is the sample look alike data i have:

```
a b c d e "f f1 f2" g
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 "f1 f11 f12" g1
```

i am trying to achieve a to g columns where f f1 and f2 comes under f but i am getting two extra column f1 and f2 that should come in column f

```
a = load 'file.txt' Using PigStorage(' ');
```

How can i do so in pig?

**Updated data**

```
a b c d e "f f1 f2" g
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 "f1 f11 f12" g1
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 "fgn f1 f11 f12" g1
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using REGEX, can you try the below approach?

**input:**

```
a b c d e "f f1 f2" g
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 "f1 f11 f12" g1
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 "fgn f1 f11 f12" g1
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+"?([A-Za-z0-9\\s]+)"?\\s+(\\w+)')) AS (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7);
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(a,b,c,d,e,f f1 f2,g)
(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1 f11 f12,g1)
(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,fgn f1 f11 f12,g1)
(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1)
```

Now `col6` variable will store the value `"f f1 f2"`  and  `"f1 f11 f12"` as a single unit.

Comment: Yes it is working for the provided value but it is not generalized it is not working with any other form like the updated data. in case of the last row it is returning no value at all but Thanks for the way i am looking into regex.

Comment: I did a mistake, instead of (1 or more match and optional double quotes), i have used (zero or more) match. with the help of Regex forum i solved this issue. Can you try the above updated script?

Comment: Yes it worked and i got how it is works. one more thing can you help me how to check in regex if my string is like "GET /pub/softpaq/sp54001-54500/sp54040.exe HTTP/1.1" apart from this question. but for the stuff u did thanks for that :)

Comment: Is this string part of your input? if so,use this regex B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+"?([A-Za-z0-9\\s\\/\\.\\-]+)"?\\s+(\\w+)')) AS (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7);